# "you're" as possessive pronoun?

Tags: possessives

afaik, you're is an abreviation of "you are", but I've seen frequently people using it as possessive pronoun (your), is that an usual mistake or is it accepted?

e.g.:

```
[...] you're users are [...]
```

Comment: Yes, its a common error.  Many people don't get apostrophes.

Comment: Many native speakers are only marginally literate. You can be a fluent speaker and illiterate or semi-literate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common mistake and is by no means accepted. *Your* means *belonging to you*, *you're* means *you are*, without exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common enough mistake that native English writers often don't bother pointing it out to others. I make it often enough when I'm writing in a hurry. I wouldn't call it acceptable. You should fix it if you can.